# XML Format Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Is there a layout that lets you format things on xml in such a way that you can position buttons and texts wherever you want and not have them change relative to other boxes? When I tried using relativelayout, it was a nightmare because moving one box made everything else move too. When I tried linearlayout, (I may have been using it wrong, but I tried for a good two hours) I couldn't move boxes exactly where I wanted, it'd go in the general direction but I couldn't fine tune the placement.

Comment: You can use combination of both :)

Comment: How can I merge them? On the xml, would I have 2 separate linearlayout and relativelayout parts or would they be nested?

Comment: `everything moves relative to each other so if I move one thing, everything else changes due to relative layout.` **NO**. All items must be placed in relation to the container and/or between them.   `When I use linearlayout, buttons can only be placed in a grid` **NO**. All items are placed consequently. Either horizontally or vertically (default), as you specify.

Comment: So you can't place it wherever, only certain spots on an invisible grid like a 3x3 square?

Comment: **NO**. That's called `GridLayout`. Or you can use a `GridView` and place your Views in it. Also `TableLayout` should do the trick.

Comment: So in linearlayout you can move things anywhere you want?

Comment: NO, they are placed next to each other vertically or horizontally, in equal sizes to fit the screen. You can adjust item sizes in `LinearLayout` with `weight`. However, you always have one root layout that determines the positioning of its items. Those children can be Layouts again. The layout places the items in general but you can adjust sizes, padding, margin etc. Post your desired layout and one can help you to arrange layouts and items.

Comment: **NO**, obviously. LinearLayout decides by itself. All Views are placed one after another.

Comment: Is that kind of similar to gridlayout then, only with columns or rows instead where you can place different buttons or textviews?

Comment: Anyway, using a RelativeLayout, you can position the Views in relation to one another. Say "place B on the top", "place A under B", "place C to the right of A", ...

Comment: **NO**. LinearLayouts are similat to **a single** row or column. Not a whole grid.

Comment: Obviously, you **could** (but are **strongly invited not to**) place layouts inside layouts. Which is a **worst practice** called `layout nesting`

Comment: I want to say place A at position 'a' and place B at position 'b', on and on. What's the best way to do that? With linear layout i felt like i couldn't place it EXACTLY at position 'a', it would only let me go to position 'c' which is near 'a' but not quite.

Comment: You shouldn't place items at exact pixel positions at all, because the layout would only work on that specific display resolution. Any screen layout should be flexibly designed for different screen sizes!

Comment: Possibly, a TableLayout is your best friend. But I insist with RelativeLayouts.

Comment: Ok the main reason I was asking this question was because I'm making an app that displays a number in the center of the screen, with other buttons around it. However, if the number gets larger or smaller (1, 2, 3 digits) then the buttons change positions according to it. How could I make the buttons stay in the same position even when the number in the center changes?

Comment: Just change the text in the central View... using a font size which isn't too big!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to place buttons wherever I want, each independent of each other

Please note there are a **huge** number of different *Android* devices on the market, with different screen sizes and resolutions.

It's your duty to adapt your application so it can run perfectly in all of them.

At your case, I highly suggest you to get used to `RelativeLayout`.

It's not difficult to understand how it works.

You can plan how the *User Interface* and *User Experience* will look like **before** creating the screen, so if you need to make any changes in the future you can minimize the work.

You can do it by either using a paper and a pen, or use some designing tools like [fluidui.com/](http://fluidui.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [AbsoluteLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html). This layout allows you to specify the X/Y coordinates of all the widgets in the layout.

However, this layout is one of the least flexible. Your screen layout will be tied directly to the resolution of the device it's created for. The Linear and Relative layouts are much more flexible when your app needs to run on a variety of phones/tablets/etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to the desired layout you described in the comment, I suggest the following:

Use a `RelativeLayout` or `GridLayout`, place the maximum number buttons you will need on it, and then show or hide the buttons dynamically with the "Visibility" XML option (the class method is [setVisibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29))of the root `View` UI class. The buttons won't show up but hold their position.

Answer (score 0):

This is the layout I used (1 **single** RelativeLayout)

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCenter"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ball"
        android:text="Btn 0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTop"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/btnCenter"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/btnCenter"
        android:background="@drawable/ball"
        android:text="Btn 1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLeft"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/btnCenter"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnCenter"
        android:background="@drawable/ball"
        android:text="Btn 2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBottom"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnCenter"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/btnCenter"
        android:background="@drawable/ball"
        android:text="Btn 3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRight"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/btnCenter"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnCenter"
        android:background="@drawable/ball"
        android:text="Btn 4"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

To get this "grid" alike design

[image]

Not optimized, I should have used a style for the buttons common attributes.

To add 4 more buttons is not a big deal.
The keyword is **relativity**.

Please note how I set the proper attributes to align all the buttons to the central one.

Anyway, there are **5** digits in these buttons, you see.
More than enough for your 1, 2 or 3 digits request.